# Uncaught TypeError: store.getState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my redux js app (google appengine backend), I get the following warnings and error message when the page containing the Root component is opened.

Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`. Check the render method of `Root`.
bundle.js:6169

Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `DevToolsWrapper`, expected `object`. Check the render method of `Root`.
bundle.js:6169

Warning: Failed Context Types: Invalid child context `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`. Check the render method of `Root`.
bundle.js:6169

Warning: Failed Context Types: Invalid context `store` of type `function` supplied to `Connect(AsyncApp)`, expected `object`. Check the render method of `Provider`.

```
Uncaught TypeError: store.getState is not a function
```

This is where the error occurs in the react-redux's lib/components/createConnect.js.

```
    function computeStateProps(store, props) {
      var state = store.getState();  <<<<< The error occurs here.
      var stateProps = shouldUpdateStateProps ? finalMapStateToProps(state, props) : finalMapStateToProps(state);

      _invariant2['default'](_utilsIsPlainObject2['default'](stateProps), '`mapStateToProps` must return an object. Instead received %s.', stateProps);
      return stateProps;
    }
```

At the breakpoint, right before this error occurs, the console.log(store) returns this.

```
function (reducer, initialState) {
      var store = next(reducer, initialState);
      var _dispatch = store.dispatch;
      var chain = [];

      var middlewareAPI = {
        getState: store.…
```

However, when I run the exact same code using Node backend, console.log(store) returns this object instead.

```
devToolsStore: Object
dispatch: (action)
getReducer: getReducer()
getState: getState()
replaceReducer: replaceReducer(nextReducer)
subscribe: subscribe(listener)
```

My root component and configureStore.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../store/configureStore';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { DevTools, DebugPanel, LogMonitor } from 'redux-devtools/lib/react';


import AsyncApp from './AsyncApp';

const store = configureStore();

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
return (
 <div>
  <Provider store={store}>
    {() => <AsyncApp />}
  </Provider>
  <DebugPanel top right bottom>
    <DevTools store={store} monitor={LogMonitor} />
  </DebugPanel>
</div>
);
}
}
```

configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } from "redux";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import loggerMiddleware from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { devTools, persistState } from 'redux-devtools';

const finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
    devTools(),
    persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/)),
    createStore
);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  return finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is you're running an older sample code. There was a [breaking change in Redux 2.0 `compose()` function API](https://github.com/rackt/redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0).

Instead of

```
const finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
    devTools(),
    persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/)),
    createStore
);
```

you probably want

```
const finalCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
    devTools(),
    persistState(window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&]+)\b/))
)(createStore);
```